# How to set default value of option in HTML?

Tags: html

, I know we can set default option value by using `selected` in option's attribute.

But Is there any way to set a default value of option from attribute in select tag . i.e when i open page that value should be selected itself , and i want to do this in select tag

Something like this

```
   <select selected= "saab">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="vw">VW</option>
    <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: can't i do  in html?

Comment: u again misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The only way, in HTML, to set the default option is to use the `selected` attribute on the option.

This avoids the need to provide `id` attributes for options (given that multiple options can share the same value) and it also because a select element can have multiple options selected at the same time (if the `multiple` attribute is set).